# How to read a table cell from an HTML Label in Dundas BI?

Tags: dundas

I want to use the value of a cell in an HTML Label

[image]

I want to use the values, for example:

- element id
- positioning in CSS
- information to execute some javascript
- texto para etiquetas 
  ...